# facing issue with apache2 installation

Tags: apache, dockerfile, apt

`facing issue while building docker file
content of my docker file:

```
RUN echo "Starting first RUN block" \
  && true \  
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install curl -y \
  && apt-get download adduser \
  && dpkg --unpack adduser*.deb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/adduser.postinst \
  && dpkg --configure adduser \
  && rm -rf adduser*.deb 

RUN echo "Starting second RUN block" \
  && true \ 
  && curl -k https://apro.nbnco.net.au/cdtools-generic/certs/openssl/cacerts.pem -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacerts.crt \
  && update-ca-certificates \
  && apt-get install -y -q openjdk-11-jre iptables apache2
```

getting error as [text](amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.56-1~deb11u2
20:28:08    Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.30.132 80])

docker build with --no-cache parameter
apt update && apt install -y apache2 in one command line instead of two
add --fix-missing at the end of apt install -y apache2

`